# Anyone commiting (regenerating snapshot artifacts) forces others to rebuilt their projets to keep what they are working on. It's the correct behavior?

Tags: java, maven

I encounter this situation at work :

1. I checkout a projet and start developing on it.
2. Others snapshots artifacts are downloaded at build time, coming in handy to create the whole application.
3. During the day, others developers are working. Some commits changes.
4. The night, snapshot artifact repository receives new snapshots artifacts including them.
5. In the morning, if I wan't to ensure my own project to retain its own behavior, I have to recompile it, and any sub-projets I have checkout to modify them. Else, snapshots artifacts mingle in my current application and its behavior isn't the one I have left the day before, under *Eclipse*.

Is it the correct behavior of *Maven* that I am seeing ?

Myself, I do not have any `-U` *update-snapshot-dependencies* written anywhere in my Maven settings. Could admins have enforced it somewhere causing what I'm seeing ?

Shouldn't a setting take place to force local artifacts to override snapshots ones, if it's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is correct and I believe it plays in your favor. It's better discovering integration problems sooner that later. If you discover that your code isn't working with other colleagues code it's a lot easier to solve the issue immediately while the context is fresh in your heads. Postponing it for few days will only increase the time necessary to do a proper integration.